# Appending To Dynamically Added Elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a div that exists when the page is loaded.  I append a button and another  to it.  I then want to click the button and append things into .

So far the first part is working but I cannot append to any elements that were created dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // THIS WORKS
    $("#Value").change(function () {
        var value = $("#Value").val();
        $("#Question_Field").empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
            $("#Question_Field").append('<input type="button" id="button" /><div id="test"></div>');
        }
    });

    // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    $("#test").click(function () {
        console.log("Click");
        ("#test").append(STUFF);
    });
});
```

It's not even logging the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems.

1. When you're hooking the event, no `#test` element exists yet, and so nothing gets hooked up.
2. You're creating multiple elements with the same `id`.

Also, your `append` call is missing a `$` at the beginning.

You can fix the first using event delegation (and this code fixes the `append` as well):

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
    console.log("Click");
    $("#test").append(STUFF);
});
```

That tells jQuery to hook the `click` event on `document`, but only fire the handler if the event originated on or passed through an element matching the given selector (`#test`) as it bubbled up to the document.

To fix the second issue, multiple elements with the same `id`, you need to change your loop outputting the elements. It could well be that you want to be using a class rather than an `id`.

Comment: Thanks.  How efficient is this?  Does it have to search through all elements until it find one that matches #test every time?  What if I had to do this with multiple elements with different ids?  Maybe something like '#test' + i

Comment: @Jeff: It's fairly efficient. When an event is created, the actual element on which the event was generated is part of that event object (`event.target`). All jQuery has to do, once the click reaches the document, is start with `event.target` and see if it matches the selector. If not, it goes to the `parentNode` of the target and checks that. If no match, it goes to the `parentNode` of *that*. Even if your HTML structure had 15 nested elements (a `div` containing another `div` containing a `table` with a `tbody`, `tr`, `td`, and nine *further* levels), well, that's only 15 elements to check.

Comment: @Jeff: If you want to match multiple `id` values, you do that exactly the way you always do that in CSS: `#test, #foo, #bar`. But any time you're listing multiple `id` values like that, you have to ask yourself if you should be using a single class instead.

Answer (score 0):

`click` can only handle elements that exist when it is called. You should check `.live()` http://api.jquery.com/live/ or `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/ depending on your jQuery version.